# How should I handle long exception handling code

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make calls to an external API. I handle four or more exceptions for the call.

If I make multiple calls, the code increases very quick. Should I be writing a wrapper for each such call which handles the exceptions and returns data?

Here is an example of such [code](http://devblog.springest.com/how-to-automatically-find-users-on-twitter/) (this is not mine).  The call to `user_search` is followed by the exception handling.

Note: I am not using Rails

```
begin
@twitter = Twitter.user_search(name)
rescue Twitter::Unauthorized
  puts "Not authorized. Please check the Twitter credentials at the top of the script."
  break

rescue Twitter::BadRequest => e
  puts "Hit rate limit. Continuing scraping at #{e.ratelimit_reset}"
  sleep e.retry_after
  retry

rescue Exception => e
  puts "Something else went wrong:"
  puts e.message
end
```

I've changed the title of the question.  I think the issue is more how to handle long exception handling code.  In the example code suppose I have multiple calls to the twitter API followed by exception handling, it seems like the exception handling code disrupts reading the code which does the actual work.

Comment: Explain what "the code increases very quick." means. It gets faster? More of it gets written?

Comment: I mean the number of lines of code increases.  It becomes difficult to read, since the 'actual' code is much less than the exception handling.

Comment: Why don't you show some samples of what you're talking about? Exception handling done wrong can mushroom out of control. Done right it can be very elegant, but, without showing us your code we're left to imagine what you've written, which is a waste of our time. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Comment: Also: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance." In both cases you haven't given us anything to go on that pertains to your particular case, so, as is, your question is a prime candidate for closing, so help us help you.

Comment: @theTinMan In the original question I posted a link to sample code.  I though that was good enough.  I will try to create another snippet. One solution that I thought of (also posted in the question) is to create a wrapper to the api call which does the exception handling.

Comment: Links to needed code or data are a problem. "Link-rot" sets in and suddenly the resource is gone. Plus, you assume people are inclined to chase down the information needed to help you; We're all volunteers doing this in spare moments. Having to look here and there wastes that time when other questions already have the info we need. So, by putting what's needed in the question, you make it easier for us to help you, and you help future people looking for similar answers.

Answer (score 1):

Write your exception handler around a chunk of code so that, if the first line in the block fails, you're happy skipping all the code up until the last line in the block.

If an exception invalidates the whole rest of the method that the handler appears in, consider letting the exception bubble up to the next layer. Not everything necessarily has to be caught by *your* method.

Often I find myself writing exception handlers around single lines of code (with suitable recovery code) but it's not a rule.

Comment: do you ever move exception handling code into a wrapper method to make the main code more readable

Comment: Not usually, a wrapper method implies changing the external API of the class - i.e. it would mean the user has to call my methods differently just because I've changed the internals (which is a bit of a no-no). Instead (*if the error handling is identical for all those methods*) I'd probably create a private method `with_error_handling [do ... end]` that takes a block, which I would call from each of the appropriate methods. So I guess there is a *kind of* wrapper in that case but not in the sense I'd normally call it.